# How to Play a YouTube Video inside a Fragment using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube-api

I'm really stuck at this problem, and I'm not able to integrate the YouTube API with my app.

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

> A fragment that contains a YouTubePlayerView. Using this fragment is the preferred way of playing YouTube videos because your activity does not need to extend an activity provided by the library, as is the case with using the YouTubePlayerView directly.

If you follow [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications) tutorials, most probably you will not have any problem.